# Unable to connect with Ethernet under 18.04

Tags: upgrade, network-manager, 18.04

I just upgraded 18.04 from 16.04 on my laptop, and the Ethernet connection cannot connect (it only uses the wireless). I have tried the command `sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` but it did not work as expected: now if I activate Ethernet connection in parameters, the system disconnect automatically (it is progress, though!).
Anyone had similar issue with 18.04 upgrade?

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution, I also have the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks!

Comment: I also have the same issue...