# How to securely upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, system, 18.04

Is it possible to upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04?

Are there any known issues with upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 so far?

What precautions can I take to minimize the potential for data loss and down time? And how do I start the update?

Thank you in advance

Charlie

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029301/upgrading-from-ubuntu-16-04-to-18-04-broke-the-system-completely/1029327#1029327

Comment: It is certainly possible.

Comment: Clone your Ubuntu and upgrade the clone. Do it many times if necessary until all kinks worked out: https://askubuntu.com/q/1028604/307523

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Yes it is possible to upgrade 16.04 to 18.04. The list of known issues is too long to post in an answer. Key "18.04" in the search bar above and you will find many hours of reading. The precautions to take are listed in my answer below. You start the upgrade with `do-release-upgrade -d` but as in my answer below do this on a cloned copy of Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 broke the system completely!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029301/upgrading-from-ubuntu-16-04-to-18-04-broke-the-system-completely)

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt err on the side of caution. The best thing to do is test, test and test some more. Using this script: [Bash script to clone Ubuntu to new partition for testing 18.04 LTS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade) you can clone your Ubuntu 16.04 to a new partition and run the upgrade to 18.04 on the new partition.

If the upgrade fails, find out why, wait for fix, clone the data again and rerun the upgrade.

After the upgrade succeeds test each application you use. If one doesn't work, find out why, wait for fix, clone the data again and rerun the upgrade.

The other part about testing is to choose which of the five unique signons you like best between Gnome, Unity, Wayland, X11 and combinations therein.

Additionally you can install new applications previously not available such as tweak tools and experiment with them. If you break something, clone the data again and rerun the upgrade.

Wash, Rinse, Repeat then Repeat again...

Answer (score 2):

### Wait for 18.04.1 LTS before upgrading

The most secure way is to wait for the first point release, 18.04.1 LTS, in July or August. At that time the early adopters have discovered several bugs and the Ubuntu developers have squashed them.

See also [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

---

But there are **always risks with upgrading** to a new version, so you should have a new good **backup** before you start this adventure.

A safer alternative is to make a fresh installation, but keep the `/home` directory as a separate partition and select it (without formatting) via 'Something else' at the partitioning window in the installer.

Answer (score 1):

I did the upgrade last Saturday and Sunday (27 Apr 2018) on my desktop and laptop. Here are the issues I faced:

- My desktop froze during the upgrade (from the Internet) and I had to do a full re-upgrade from CD. Following this I was unable to launch a terminal for manual command, so I re-installed the whole thing, and it is running fine since. Desktop is running AMD Phenom IIx4, with 12Gb memory.
- My laptop upgrade was more successful: kept all my files system, but the Ethernet connection isn't recognized anymore (I can access Internet through Wi-Fi only), despite the updates made on 30 Apr 18 (see: [Unable to connect with Ethernet under 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029724/823619)). Laptop is running Intel Core2 T9800 CPU, with 8Gb memory.

Comment: For other readers you can avoid this by cloning your data to a new partition (https://askubuntu.com/a/1028605/307523) and upgrading to 18.04. Then repeat the process many times over weeks or months until all errors are resolved either by Ubuntu bug fixes and/or your own custom scripts.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there are no risks whatsoever. Canonical even states that it's safe. They did say that it would be easier, however, to simply reinstall the OS later on than upgrading. [Here's](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop?_ga=2.7076338.1533777877.1525116553-1695487630.1521978797) a link to their guide on upgrading to another version (NOTE: it didn't work on my install, but I didn't have a good, reliable internet connection).

Comment: There are lots of risks. Key "18.04" into search bar. Sort the results by date and you'll see many problems every hour.

Comment: "As far as I know, there are no risks whatsoever." a ludicrous comment if there ever is one. Change means risk, always. Sometime a lot some times not. Risk increases with complexity, but you can always mitigate it. How far you go depends on the cost of loss if it all screws up. 1st of all backup/clone/replicate. If its a production system duplicate it and play with the upgrade on the duplicate...

Comment: _“Canonical even states that it's safe.”_ Please provide a link to the source. I’ve found the opposite: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS