# Problems with installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (grub)

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 18.04

When installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS when the installation comes to the installation of "grub 2", it terminates and gives an error:

```
could not install the grub bootloader into target.
```

But the version of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and other distributions are installed without such problems. Please tell me what to do?

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Sometimes running Boot-Repair fixes reinstalls grub. Report will tell if installing UEFI or BIOS boot mode.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to install grub onto your system?  Please edit this question and provide with more detail.

Comment: Rather than installing `18.04` you can [clone your `16.04`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030268/how-to-securely-upgrade-ubuntu-from-16-04-to-18-04/1030348#1030348) to a test partition and upgrade it to 18.04 by rebooting to 16.04 clone and using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. You can repeat the cloning and upgrading many times until you are satisfied the new `18.04` passes the smell test. It might take a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Most likely you are missing ESP partition on your first drive.

-Start install again

-Chose "something else" option when prompted

-Resize your sda1 partition and mount it as root

-Make new partition of 100-200Mb and for type select ESP

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the partition division make room for installation. Prepare for ESP menu options and bootloader.

Comment: Your answer is a bit short. Please add some more information and guidance on how to do what you mentioned there, so that less experienced users can find it helpful as well. Thank you.